# Error : Module '"@angular/material"' has no exported member "..."

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular12

i create a custom Angular material module, material.module.ts file and import the following Angular material UI components in this file like given below.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import {
   MatButtonModule,
   MatToolbarModule,
   MatIconModule,
   MatBadgeModule,
   MatSidenavModule,
   MatListModule,
   MatGridListModule,
   MatFormFieldModule,
   MatInputModule,
   MatSelectModule,
   MatRadioModule,
   MatDatepickerModule,
   MatNativeDateModule,
   MatChipsModule,
   MatTooltipModule,
   MatTableModule,
   MatPaginatorModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
   imports: [
      CommonModule,
      MatButtonModule,
      MatToolbarModule,
      MatIconModule,
      MatSidenavModule,
      MatBadgeModule,
      MatListModule,
      MatGridListModule,
      MatFormFieldModule,
      MatInputModule,
      MatSelectModule,
      MatRadioModule,
      MatDatepickerModule,
      MatNativeDateModule,
      MatChipsModule,
      MatTooltipModule,
      MatTableModule,
      MatPaginatorModule
   ],
   exports: [
      MatButtonModule,
      MatToolbarModule,
      MatIconModule,
      MatSidenavModule,
      MatBadgeModule,
      MatListModule,
      MatGridListModule,
      MatInputModule,
      MatFormFieldModule,
      MatSelectModule,
      MatRadioModule,
      MatDatepickerModule,
      MatChipsModule,
      MatTooltipModule,
      MatTableModule,
      MatPaginatorModule
   ],
   providers: [
      MatDatepickerModule,
   ]
})

export class AngularMaterialModule { }
```

And import the AngularMaterialModule to app.module.ts file
but i have this error :

> Module '"@angular/material"' has no exported member "...."

Comment: Hi and welcome. Could you provide a full sample error message, where the missing exported member is visible? How did you import your custom material module?

Comment: It is better to import the material modules that you needed for the custom module that you are working on. It can improve your code.

Answer (score 51):

You have probably updated your angular and/or angular material versions; with the angular material 9 upgrade they changed the imports from **`@angular/material`** notation to **`@angular/material/button`** like notation.

> Instead of importing from @angular/material, you should import deeply from the specific component. E.g. @angular/material/button. **ng update** will do this automatically for you.

You can follow the upgrade guide from this link:
https://update.angular.io/?v=8.0-9.0

Answer (score 18):

From Angular Material v9, each module should be imported from a separated path, e.g:

```
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
```

If you updated your Angular app using `ng update` (it's recommended to update Angular using `ng update`, but it's not recommended to move across multiple major versions, [see here for more details](https://update.angular.io/?v=7.2-12.0)), it will be migrated automatically, and you don't need to do anything regarding the import.

Answer (score 6):

you have probably updated your angular and/or angular material versions; with the angular material 9 upgrade they changed the way we import material modules in the .ts files. Previously , for every specific import of a material module like MatButtonModule,MatToolbarModule,MatIconModule,MatSidenavModule,MatBadgeModule,    MatListModule,MatGridListModule,MatInputModule,MatFormFieldModule,MatSelectModule,MatRadioModule,MatDatepickerModule,MatChipsModule,MatTooltipModule,MatTableModule,      MatPaginatorModule, (examples) we are importing in this structure

```
 import { MatButtonModule,MatToolbarModule,MatIconModule,MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material';
```

with update of Angular/ Angular material we are importing through a specific module to avoid loading of the entire material module which effects the performance and bundle size , with latest versions we are importing a specific module

```
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';`
in `app.module.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

I want to use a stepper from Angular Material. The same error as yours was displayed. I used the following code in app.module.js: import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';. In my case, "/stepper" was missing.
And in imports [MatStepperModule].